# How can I make this shape with Displacement modifier

Tags: displacement, text-object

In my previous post, I learnt how to use the displacement modifier, adding an Alpha PNG shape. @moonboots, explained to me how to use this method. The circle pattern shape turned out well on a flat square mesh. But this time I'm trying to make it on a circular mesh.

I used a Boolean object to make the circle shape, by cutting into a plane mesh which was heavily subdivided. And the border of the circle shape is jagged.

What is another method to get it correctly modelled?

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: In the previous question you show an image of some kind of bowl. Do you mean a circle shape or some kind of curved or domed shape?

Comment: Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the *Knife Project* tool:

Create a plane, subdivide it, create a circle object that you put over the plane:

[image]

Switch to top view, select the plane, switch to *Edit* mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to select the circle, then *Mesh > Knife Project*:

[image]

Invert the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and delete the edges:

[image]

Here is the result, you can use the *Displace* modifier on it:

[image]