# How to turn each one of the selected vertices into circle with loop tools?

Tags: modeling, bevel, loop

[image]

---

I'm using the bevel tool to make this pattern
[image]

---

But when I try to apply the loop tools it gets messy, if I select one by one and apply it works fine but that's a lot of work, is there a way to make it automatically?

[image]

Comment: Hello, it won't work this way, what are you trying to achieve exactly? Maybe see my answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315283/how-can-i-make-this-shape-with-displacement-modifier

Comment: what I want is to turn each one of these bevel into a circle

Comment: it will only work for the outer selection, what final topology are you trying to achieve? If you want concentric circle why don't you begin with a circle that you loopcut?

Comment: Please, take a look at [this image](https://imgur.com/a/KHLA4Tx), I'm looking for a way to turn all at once into a circle

Comment: OK please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subdivide a plane, switch to edge select mode:

[image]

Select all the inner edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel then <kbd>V</kbd> to switch to vertex bevel:

[image]

Change the *Width* value in the *Operator Box* to have the circular shape:

[image]